# Account doesn't appear in contacts app settings on device from HTC

Tags: android, contacts, htc-android

I write my own SyncAdapter based on example in SDK. It should add contacts from external source, and it works perfect in device emulator. But when I run it on HTC Desire after all I can't see my Account in Contacts->Display options

Also I tried google's example on Desire and couldn't see them in this list too. Does anyone know any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve it by making my account visible by default.

```
ContentProviderClient client = getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY_URI);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ContactsContract.Settings.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
values.put(ContactsContract.Settings.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
values.put(ContactsContract.Settings.UNGROUPED_VISIBLE, true);
try
{
  client.insert(Settings.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true").build(), values);
}
catch (RemoteException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

after that account is visible by default, and you can see it in accounts list in contacts

Comment: Must this be called from the syncadapter?

Comment: This does nothing in my situation.. Does it need to have at least one contact to show up?

Comment: It worked in 2010 with HTC Desire. A lot of things changed since this time =)

Comment: Figured out what the problem was: I didn't use the ContactsContract.AUTHORITY_URI but my own autority. This works when you don't want to use groups.

Answer (score 0):

To make your account visible in ***"Display options"*** of standard ***Contacts*** application you should have `SyncAdapter` in your application and it's meta-data specified in `syncadapter.xml` as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#SyncAdapters).

Moreover you should specify using of [`android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS) permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

`UNGROUPED_VISIBLE` make it visible only for list of contacts groups.