# My application contacts in the phone contacts list

Tags: android, contacts

I'm trying to build an application where my contacts are merged with the phone contacts (similar, as Google, Facebook, LinkedIn).

I built the sync adapter and I added automatically into accounts. I also have a content provider with a table of contacts.
I followed the following topic [How to make a custom account show up like Google/LinkedIn/Facebook in the native Contacts app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244334/how-to-make-a-custom-account-show-up-like-google-linkedin-facebook-in-the-native).

So, I have my own uri and table of contacts. 
From here I don't know how to link the items from my table with the phone contacts

Answer (score 0):

After reading many other discussions simply I need to:

```
    Uri myUri = uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(ContactsContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true").build();

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(uri)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_NAME)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, ACCOUNT_TYPE)
            //.withValue(RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, 12345)
            //.withValue(RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED)
            .build());

    resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```